# Can TypeScript output an anonymous AMD module output, instead of named?

Tags: javascript, typescript, amd

TypeScript `tsc` outputs something like

```
define("app", ["require", "exports", "foo", function(foo) {
    // ...
});
```

Can we make it output an anonymous module like

```
define(["require", "exports", "foo", function(foo) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: It depends. If you use --outDir, it should generate separate anonymous module for every `.ts` file. If you use --outFile, it should compile all `.ts` files into single amd file (bundle) containing named `define`s, and there no way (and no point) to make them anonymous AFAIK.

Comment: @artem Well, then if you put that as the answer I can accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

TypeScript emits named defines when `--outFile` option is present, requesting it to generate single file (bundle) containing all compiled modules. Then, when module format is `amd`, each module will be represented as named `define` call, because AFAIK it does not make sense to have multiple anonymous defines in one file.

Anonymous `define` is emitted when `--outFile` is absent, then you have either `--outDir` or default behavior of generating `.js` files next to `.ts` files, and for `amd` module format each module is emitted as separate file that contains anonymous `define`.